# "Retrieves and let you print" or "Retrieves and lets you print"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verb-agreement

Speaking of some program, which of these sentences is correct?

> 1. Retrieves and let you print...
> 2. Retrieves and lets you print...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second one is correct, "retrieves and lets". Both verbs refer to the same singular noun, "program".